# Selenium Web Driver:How can I include the details of emailable report of testNG in email using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written below mentioned code to attach TestNG's emailable report in email using java.
Now I want to paste the details of emailable report in body of the email using java.Anyone having idea on this?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMailSSL {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            final Properties props = new Properties();
            try {
                props.load(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("Mail/Credentials.properties"));
                String Username = props.getProperty("username");
                String Password= props.getProperty("password");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "x");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");



            Session session = Session.getInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(props.getProperty("username"),props.getProperty("password"));
                }
              });

            try {

                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("x"));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("x"));
                message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
                message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                    + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

                Transport.send(message);

                System.out.println("Done");

            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What testing framework are you using? Junit? NUnit? They generally produce an XML file at the end of the tests anyway, to detail it's results.

Comment: I am using TestNG.Yes results are generated in index.xml.But I want to paste the results in mail when broadcasting to group.Do you have any idea on that?